# Compress image before save into zip file

Tags: android, image, file, zip, compression

I've code to create zip file with images within as below

```
public void zip(String[] files, String zipFile) {

    final String[] _files = files;
    final String _zipFile = zipFile;

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                BufferedInputStream origin = null;
                FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(_zipFile);

                ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(dest));

                byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

                for (int i = 0; i < _files.length; i++) {
                    Log.d("add:", _files[i]);
                    Log.v("Compress", "Adding: " + _files[i]);
                    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(_files[i]);
                    origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);
                    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(_files[i].substring(_files[i].lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
                    out.putNextEntry(entry);
                    int count;
                    while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                        out.write(data, 0, count);
                    }
                    origin.close();
                }

                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

I'm call the method zip(stockArr,"/storage/sdcard0/MyAnnouncementImages.zip"), the images are not compressed then if each picture weighs 3Mb the zip file is going to be so heavy, then  i need compress each images before put inside the zip file, some help?

Comment: What kind of images are you trying to compress?  Many types of image files are already compressed.

Comment: all kind of images, i need some like this compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, outputStream)  to reduce the image size

Comment: If your files are JPEG or PNG images, they're already compressed and you can't make them smaller without redoing the entire image at a lower quality.  How much compression do you get if you manually compress your files with a command like `gzip -9 image.bmp` or `gzip -9 image.jpg`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you try with Bitmap?

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(capturedImage, width, height, true);
```

Specify width and height of the bitmap so... the height and width you can set according to the screen dpi of the device.

Comment: How i can add to the code that i showed? I not have idea how to aggregate because stockarr is a string[] then first i have to do is convert to bitmap and next convert again to string each position...